# How to handle expired token from server-side

Tags: facebook-access-token

I have to admit the process of renewing an expired token at the server-side, because the FB user has logged out, confuses me. The solution to handle expired tokens, [as presented on this page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/), would only seem to work if the user was viewing a server page that could prompt said user to re-authorise the app (JS location.href redirection to a FB dialog URL).

What if a server side app has saved the access token because of some processing that will take some time first? If after some hours/days the server wants to post something to the user's wall, using the either the short or a long term token, but the user has logged out of Facebook - what then? Sure, the request will fail because of the logged out status of the user, but this seems to me to also mean the server will have no valid way of posting to the user's wall until they log back in to Facebook (and the app happens to try to post again at the right time).

Am I right here or missing something obvious? Seems a crazy scenario to prevent a server-based application from posting to a pre-authorised user's wall just because said user has logged out (which i'm sure many, many users do on a regular basis). Why does logging out == deauthorising the access token? And, if the user logged back in, does the existing access token become valid again, or is a whole new token required (assume we have obtained a 60 day token)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does logging out == deauthorising the access token?

It doesn’t. A long-term access token doesn’t get invalid just because the user logs out of Facebook!

So get a long-term one, valid for sixty days – and you’re good to go to post or do whatever a few days after requiring the token. If the 60 days are over and the user hasn’t interacted with your app since, then you have to have the user come back to your app to get a new token.

Comment: My point is that, if the user logs out of Facebook, any attempt to post to their wall (or whatever) using the short OR long term token will apparently fail, according to the information in the link I provided:

`What many developers do not realize is that an access token can also expire if a user changes her password, **logs out** or if she de-authorizes the app via the App Dashboard.`

(my emphasis)

Comment: This documentation is outdated, since offline_access permission is deprecated. Read this: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: The link I posted is from the page you now reference, and if you read the last section of your link you'll see reference is again made to handling expired tokens due to user log out.

Comment: The long-term tokens shouldn't expire on log-out

Comment: I agree Igy, however the official documentation says they will. It's a strange one.

Comment: Having finally found the time to test tokens, I can confirm that extended tokens can still be used after a user has logged out. The same operation fails if using the normal temp token. FB documentation could be clearer imo